# React-Native TextInput numeric keyboard without dot and comma

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

I need to use the numeric keyboard on my app but in some smartphones the numeric keyboard dont have comma or dot there any fix for this? or some thing else to avoid it?

Code: I'm using Native-Base, but even without it the result is the same

```
class CampoFloat extends Component {
    render() {
        const { ...props } = this.props;
        return (
            <View>
                <Item floatingLabel style={styles.Item}>
                    <Label style={{
                        color: '#323232',
                        fontSize: 18,
                        marginTop: 5
                    }}>{this.props.titulo}</Label>
                    <Input
                        style={styles.input}
                        {...props}
                    />
                </Item>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

<CampoFloat
     titulo="Preço do produto:"
     autoCorrect={false}
     keyboardType="numeric"
     onChangeText={(event) => this.setState({ preco: event })}
/>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Try with phone-pad

Comment: phone-pad show the same as default

Comment: check this image https://image.slidesharecdn.com/l5-react-native-input-state-160913041941/95/react-native-tutorial-lecture-5-input-and-state-10-638.jpg?cb=1488423688

Comment: So this only works on 6.0+? lower devices won't able to use it ?

Comment: what is your device android version. No it will be work, might be some thing is missing in style or format section. Share your device specification as well.

Comment: The device i'm using is an LG G3 with Android (5.0.2), the phone-pad worked well now, but what i need is the numeric keyboard https://imgur.com/a/mvhYR

Comment: Okay then try with inputView. Also check this out might be it will help u https://github.com/beefe/react-native-keyboard

Comment: Didn't work this component is deprecated :(

Comment: @AlessandroMacanha have you found solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's default keyboard from factory, you should use Google Gboard and it will work without coding.

Answer (score -4):

As per facebook doc ReactNative has for types of keyboard for Android so try with that

```
<TextInput
  key={phone ? 'input-phone' : 'input-default'}
  keyboardType={phone ? 'phone-pad' : 'default'}
/>
```